# C++ classes: create copy of "this" class within member function

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword

I'm trying to write a function for the `+=` operator of a C++ class which utilizes the already written `+` operator function. So far, I have been unsuccessful in associating the `this` pointer with the `+` operator. These are some of the attempts I've made that compiled in `g++` but did not produce the desired result. Twice I attempted simply to make a copy of the `this` class, but that did not appear to work.

```c++
intstr& intstr::operator+=(const intstr& i)
{
  intstr *a;
  a = new intstr;
  *a = *this + i;
  return *a;
}
```

```c++
intstr& intstr::operator+=(const intstr& i)
{
  intstr *a, b(*this);
  a = new intstr;
  *a = b + i;
  return *a;
}
```

```c++
intstr& intstr::operator+=(const intstr& i)
{
  intstr *a, *b;
  a = new intstr;
  b = this;
  *a = *b + i;
  return *a;
}
```

```c++
intstr& intstr::operator+=(const intstr& i)
{
  intstr *a;
  a = new intstr;
  *a = this->operator+(i);
  return *a;
}
```

In the test code, all I've done is replace the working line of code `a = a + i` with `a += i`, so I doubt the problem lies there, but it is possible. Is the only way to do this to copy the code from the `+` operator into the `+=` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate (and recommended reading anyway): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator can look like

```
intstr& intstr::operator+=( const intstr& i )
{
   *this = *this + i;

   return *this;
}
```

If the `operator +` is declared as a class member function then you can also write

```
intstr& intstr::operator+=( const intstr& i )
{
   *this = operator +( i ); // or *this = this->operator +( i );  

   return *this;
}
```

It would be a mistake to allocate dynamically an object of type intstr within the operator. At least there is no such a need to do this.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I knew there had to be a simple way to do this.

Comment: @Vlad Is it also ok if we use return ( operator + ( i )); ?

Comment: @sameer karjatkar No it would not be o'k. Operator + may not change the left operand. It may return a temporary object even a const temporary object.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the approach is the opposite: you implement `operator+=` and then you implement `operator+` using that implementation (create a copy of the first argument, then use `+=` to increment by the second argument and return that).

Other than that, why are you calling `new` in all versions? For `operator+=` you don't need to create any new object at all. The operator should modify the value of the left-hand-side operand by incrementing it with the value of the right-hand-side. No new objects need to be created anywhere (and less so dynamically allocated with `new`!)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! At first, I didn't think I needed "new", but it wasn't until I used it that my code compiled, so I just went with it. I never thought to use "+=" first and derive "+" from that - good to know! I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do it the other way around:

```
intstr& intstr::operator+=(intstr const& rhs)
{
     // Do this stuff to add rhs into this object.
     return *this;
}

// Then + is implemented in terms of +=
intstr intstr::operator+(intstr const& rhs)
{
    instr  result(*this);   // Make a copy as the result
    result += rhs;
    return result;
}

// Then your free functions as needed.
```

Comment: I am not sure..don't u think the  result object would be destroyed at the end of the operator function ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar: No it will be returned by value. Remember the `operator+` creates a new value you return by value to get it out of the function.